# Creating column with value based on condition in other columns

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I got this df

```
structure(list(subj = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), adm_number = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), label_2 = c("dead", 
"dead", "dead", "dead", "dead", "dead", "dead", "dead", "dead", 
"dead", "dead", "alive", "alive", "alive", "alive", "alive", 
"alive", "alive", "alive", "alive", "alive", "alive", "alive", 
"dead", "dead", "dead", "dead", "dead", "dead", "dead", "dead", 
"dead"), dateIN = structure(c(14213, 14270, 14377, 14384, 14407, 
14415, 14442, 14714, 14893, 14988, 15091, 13773, 14343, 15446, 
15454, 15480, 15571, 15601, 15672, 15692, 14104, 15417, 15523, 
13188, 14308, 14431, 14930, 14948, 13498, 13539, 14169, 14278
), class = "Date"), dateOUT = structure(c(14225, 14291, 14379, 
14389, 14411, 14420, 14447, 14719, 14896, 14991, 15092, 13783, 
14351, 15450, 15479, 15485, 15573, 15610, 15689, 15702, 14142, 
15418, 15541, 13204, 14319, 14445, 14936, 14962, 13507, 13551, 
14177, 14285), class = "Date"), dateCENS = structure(c(15092, 
15092, 15092, 15092, 15092, 15092, 15092, 15092, 15092, 15092, 
15092, 15705, 15705, 15705, 15705, 15705, 15705, 15705, 15705, 
15705, 15705, 15705, 15705, 13985, 14962, 14962, 14962, 14962, 
15623, 15623, 15623, 15623), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-32L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7ffc190152e0>)
```

I want to create an extra column(label_3) like this

```
    structure(list(subj = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), adm_number = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), label_2 = c("dead", 
"dead", "dead", "dead", "dead", "dead", "dead", "dead", "dead", 
"dead", "dead", "alive", "alive", "alive", "alive", "alive", 
"alive", "alive", "alive", "alive", "alive", "alive", "alive", 
"dead", "dead", "dead", "dead", "dead", "dead", "dead", "dead", 
"dead"), dateIN = structure(c(14213, 14270, 14377, 14384, 14407, 
14415, 14442, 14714, 14893, 14988, 15091, 13773, 14343, 15446, 
15454, 15480, 15571, 15601, 15672, 15692, 14104, 15417, 15523, 
13188, 14308, 14431, 14930, 14948, 13498, 13539, 14169, 14278
), class = "Date"), dateOUT = structure(c(14225, 14291, 14379, 
14389, 14411, 14420, 14447, 14719, 14896, 14991, 15092, 13783, 
14351, 15450, 15479, 15485, 15573, 15610, 15689, 15702, 14142, 
15418, 15541, 13204, 14319, 14445, 14936, 14962, 13507, 13551, 
14177, 14285), class = "Date"), dateCENS = structure(c(15092, 
15092, 15092, 15092, 15092, 15092, 15092, 15092, 15092, 15092, 
15092, 15705, 15705, 15705, 15705, 15705, 15705, 15705, 15705, 
15705, 15705, 15705, 15705, 13985, 14962, 14962, 14962, 14962, 
15623, 15623, 15623, 15623), class = "Date"), label_3 = c("dead_in", 
"dead_in", "dead_in", "dead_in", "dead_in", "dead_in", "dead_in", 
"dead_in", "dead_in", "dead_in", "dead_in", "alive", "alive", 
"alive", "alive", "alive", "alive", "alive", "alive", "alive", 
"alive", "alive", "alive", "dead_out", "dead_in", "dead_in", 
"dead_in", "dead_in", "dead_out", "dead_out", "dead_out", "dead_out"
)), row.names = c(NA, -32L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7ffc190152e0>)
```

Basically, I want the status as dead_in if label_2 == dead and dateCENS is within dateIN and dateOUT, and status as dead_out if dateCENS is outside dateIN and dateOUT and alive otherwise when label_2 == alive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your desired `status` is inconsistent:

```r
     subj adm_number label_2     dateIN    dateOUT   dateCENS  label_3
    <int>      <int>  <char>     <Date>     <Date>     <Date>   <char>
 1:     1          1    dead 2008-11-30 2008-12-12 2011-04-28  dead_in <-- dateCENS > dateOUT
 2:     1          2    dead 2009-01-26 2009-02-16 2011-04-28  dead_in <-- "
 3:     1          3    dead 2009-05-13 2009-05-15 2011-04-28  dead_in <-- "
 4:     1          4    dead 2009-05-20 2009-05-25 2011-04-28  dead_in <-- "
 5:     1          5    dead 2009-06-12 2009-06-16 2011-04-28  dead_in <-- "
 6:     1          6    dead 2009-06-20 2009-06-25 2011-04-28  dead_in <-- "
 7:     1          7    dead 2009-07-17 2009-07-22 2011-04-28  dead_in <-- "
 8:     1          8    dead 2010-04-15 2010-04-20 2011-04-28  dead_in <-- "
 9:     1          9    dead 2010-10-11 2010-10-14 2011-04-28  dead_in <-- "
10:     1         10    dead 2011-01-14 2011-01-17 2011-04-28  dead_in <-- "
11:     1         11    dead 2011-04-27 2011-04-28 2011-04-28  dead_in
12:     2          1   alive 2007-09-17 2007-09-27 2012-12-31    alive 
13:     2          2   alive 2009-04-09 2009-04-17 2012-12-31    alive    
14:     2          3   alive 2012-04-16 2012-04-20 2012-12-31    alive    
15:     2          4   alive 2012-04-24 2012-05-19 2012-12-31    alive    
16:     2          5   alive 2012-05-20 2012-05-25 2012-12-31    alive    
17:     2          6   alive 2012-08-19 2012-08-21 2012-12-31    alive    
18:     3          1   alive 2012-09-18 2012-09-27 2012-12-31    alive    
19:     3          2   alive 2012-11-28 2012-12-15 2012-12-31    alive    
20:     3          3   alive 2012-12-18 2012-12-28 2012-12-31    alive    
21:     4          1   alive 2008-08-13 2008-09-20 2012-12-31    alive    
22:     4          2   alive 2012-03-18 2012-03-19 2012-12-31    alive    
23:     4          3   alive 2012-07-02 2012-07-20 2012-12-31    alive    
24:     5          1    dead 2006-02-09 2006-02-25 2008-04-16 dead_out 
25:     6          1    dead 2009-03-05 2009-03-16 2010-12-19  dead_in <-- dateCENS > dateOUT
26:     6          2    dead 2009-07-06 2009-07-20 2010-12-19  dead_in <-- "
27:     6          3    dead 2010-11-17 2010-11-23 2010-12-19  dead_in <-- "
28:     6          4    dead 2010-12-05 2010-12-19 2010-12-19  dead_in  
29:     7          1    dead 2006-12-16 2006-12-25 2012-10-10 dead_out 
30:     7          2    dead 2007-01-26 2007-02-07 2012-10-10 dead_out 
31:     7          3    dead 2008-10-17 2008-10-25 2012-10-10 dead_out 
32:     7          4    dead 2009-02-03 2009-02-10 2012-10-10 dead_out 
     subj adm_number label_2     dateIN    dateOUT   dateCENS  label_3
```

That aside, I think the trick is to use `data.table::fcase`:

```r
df[, status := fcase(
  label_2 == "dead" & between(dateCENS, dateIN, dateOUT), "dead_in",
  label_2 == "dead", "dead_out",
  rep(TRUE, .N), "alive")
][]
#      subj adm_number label_2     dateIN    dateOUT   dateCENS   status
#     <int>      <int>  <char>     <Date>     <Date>     <Date>   <char>
#  1:     1          1    dead 2008-11-30 2008-12-12 2011-04-28 dead_out
#  2:     1          2    dead 2009-01-26 2009-02-16 2011-04-28 dead_out
#  3:     1          3    dead 2009-05-13 2009-05-15 2011-04-28 dead_out
#  4:     1          4    dead 2009-05-20 2009-05-25 2011-04-28 dead_out
#  5:     1          5    dead 2009-06-12 2009-06-16 2011-04-28 dead_out
#  6:     1          6    dead 2009-06-20 2009-06-25 2011-04-28 dead_out
#  7:     1          7    dead 2009-07-17 2009-07-22 2011-04-28 dead_out
#  8:     1          8    dead 2010-04-15 2010-04-20 2011-04-28 dead_out
#  9:     1          9    dead 2010-10-11 2010-10-14 2011-04-28 dead_out
# 10:     1         10    dead 2011-01-14 2011-01-17 2011-04-28 dead_out
# 11:     1         11    dead 2011-04-27 2011-04-28 2011-04-28  dead_in
# 12:     2          1   alive 2007-09-17 2007-09-27 2012-12-31    alive
# 13:     2          2   alive 2009-04-09 2009-04-17 2012-12-31    alive
# 14:     2          3   alive 2012-04-16 2012-04-20 2012-12-31    alive
# 15:     2          4   alive 2012-04-24 2012-05-19 2012-12-31    alive
# 16:     2          5   alive 2012-05-20 2012-05-25 2012-12-31    alive
# 17:     2          6   alive 2012-08-19 2012-08-21 2012-12-31    alive
# 18:     3          1   alive 2012-09-18 2012-09-27 2012-12-31    alive
# 19:     3          2   alive 2012-11-28 2012-12-15 2012-12-31    alive
# 20:     3          3   alive 2012-12-18 2012-12-28 2012-12-31    alive
# 21:     4          1   alive 2008-08-13 2008-09-20 2012-12-31    alive
# 22:     4          2   alive 2012-03-18 2012-03-19 2012-12-31    alive
# 23:     4          3   alive 2012-07-02 2012-07-20 2012-12-31    alive
# 24:     5          1    dead 2006-02-09 2006-02-25 2008-04-16 dead_out
# 25:     6          1    dead 2009-03-05 2009-03-16 2010-12-19 dead_out
# 26:     6          2    dead 2009-07-06 2009-07-20 2010-12-19 dead_out
# 27:     6          3    dead 2010-11-17 2010-11-23 2010-12-19 dead_out
# 28:     6          4    dead 2010-12-05 2010-12-19 2010-12-19  dead_in
# 29:     7          1    dead 2006-12-16 2006-12-25 2012-10-10 dead_out
# 30:     7          2    dead 2007-01-26 2007-02-07 2012-10-10 dead_out
# 31:     7          3    dead 2008-10-17 2008-10-25 2012-10-10 dead_out
# 32:     7          4    dead 2009-02-03 2009-02-10 2012-10-10 dead_out
#      subj adm_number label_2     dateIN    dateOUT   dateCENS   status
```

The abbreviated second conditional (just `label_2 == "dead"`) is possible because if `dateCENS` *is* between in/out, then the first conditional would be used; when we get to the second, it's clear that the previous condition was false. The same effect logically (at slightly-reduced calculation) is had with:

```r
df[, status := fcase(
  label_2 == "dead" &  between(dateCENS, dateIN, dateOUT), "dead_in",
  label_2 == "dead" & !between(dateCENS, dateIN, dateOUT), "dead_out",
  rep(TRUE, .N), "alive")
]
```

---

**Edit**: I think you want some `any` or `all` logic.

```r
df[, status := fcase(
#   label_2 == "dead" & any(between(dateCENS, dateIN, dateOUT)), "dead_in",
#   label_2 == "dead" & all(!between(dateCENS, dateIN, dateOUT)), "dead_out",
#   rep(TRUE, .N), "alive")
# , by = .(subj)]
+ + +      subj adm_number label_2     dateIN    dateOUT   dateCENS  label_3   status
#     <int>      <int>  <char>     <Date>     <Date>     <Date>   <char>   <char>
#  1:     1          1    dead 2008-11-30 2008-12-12 2011-04-28  dead_in  dead_in
#  2:     1          2    dead 2009-01-26 2009-02-16 2011-04-28  dead_in  dead_in
#  3:     1          3    dead 2009-05-13 2009-05-15 2011-04-28  dead_in  dead_in
#  4:     1          4    dead 2009-05-20 2009-05-25 2011-04-28  dead_in  dead_in
#  5:     1          5    dead 2009-06-12 2009-06-16 2011-04-28  dead_in  dead_in
#  6:     1          6    dead 2009-06-20 2009-06-25 2011-04-28  dead_in  dead_in
#  7:     1          7    dead 2009-07-17 2009-07-22 2011-04-28  dead_in  dead_in
#  8:     1          8    dead 2010-04-15 2010-04-20 2011-04-28  dead_in  dead_in
#  9:     1          9    dead 2010-10-11 2010-10-14 2011-04-28  dead_in  dead_in
# 10:     1         10    dead 2011-01-14 2011-01-17 2011-04-28  dead_in  dead_in
# 11:     1         11    dead 2011-04-27 2011-04-28 2011-04-28  dead_in  dead_in
# 12:     2          1   alive 2007-09-17 2007-09-27 2012-12-31    alive    alive
# 13:     2          2   alive 2009-04-09 2009-04-17 2012-12-31    alive    alive
# 14:     2          3   alive 2012-04-16 2012-04-20 2012-12-31    alive    alive
# 15:     2          4   alive 2012-04-24 2012-05-19 2012-12-31    alive    alive
# 16:     2          5   alive 2012-05-20 2012-05-25 2012-12-31    alive    alive
# 17:     2          6   alive 2012-08-19 2012-08-21 2012-12-31    alive    alive
# 18:     3          1   alive 2012-09-18 2012-09-27 2012-12-31    alive    alive
# 19:     3          2   alive 2012-11-28 2012-12-15 2012-12-31    alive    alive
# 20:     3          3   alive 2012-12-18 2012-12-28 2012-12-31    alive    alive
# 21:     4          1   alive 2008-08-13 2008-09-20 2012-12-31    alive    alive
# 22:     4          2   alive 2012-03-18 2012-03-19 2012-12-31    alive    alive
# 23:     4          3   alive 2012-07-02 2012-07-20 2012-12-31    alive    alive
# 24:     5          1    dead 2006-02-09 2006-02-25 2008-04-16 dead_out dead_out
# 25:     6          1    dead 2009-03-05 2009-03-16 2010-12-19  dead_in  dead_in
# 26:     6          2    dead 2009-07-06 2009-07-20 2010-12-19  dead_in  dead_in
# 27:     6          3    dead 2010-11-17 2010-11-23 2010-12-19  dead_in  dead_in
# 28:     6          4    dead 2010-12-05 2010-12-19 2010-12-19  dead_in  dead_in
# 29:     7          1    dead 2006-12-16 2006-12-25 2012-10-10 dead_out dead_out
# 30:     7          2    dead 2007-01-26 2007-02-07 2012-10-10 dead_out dead_out
# 31:     7          3    dead 2008-10-17 2008-10-25 2012-10-10 dead_out dead_out
# 32:     7          4    dead 2009-02-03 2009-02-10 2012-10-10 dead_out dead_out
#      subj adm_number label_2     dateIN    dateOUT   dateCENS  label_3   status
```

(`label_3` is yours, `status` is mine.)

Comment: I get similar results when using ifelse . The issue is that subject1 is actually dead_in but the code only assign that to the last observation (obs 11) where the condition is met. I want somehow the result if it is met at the max observation then assign that status throughout. I basically want the subject's status at the dateCENS.

Comment: *"subject's status at the dateCENS"* is what this answer provides, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it does but I wanted it to repeat that status from the beginning. I guess may be a separate column or df might help.?

Comment: I really don't know what you want. I think you want each `subj`'s first row to determine the `status` for all rows of that `subj`, but still your expected output is inconsistent with even that. Please take a moment to clear up the confusion in your sample data and new logic to your question.

Comment: I want for example when we know the status of a patients at the dateCENS, to be assigned to that patient for future use. The patient status might be dead_out as in the case of subject 1 in the data but dies during the hospitalisation and now thats the status I want to hold for that patiets.

Comment: I have the latest version of data.table (1.14.0) installed and loaded but getting the error that "cant find function fcase". Very strange. Do you have any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: Installed, sure, did you `library(data.table)`? If yes, I suggest you try restarting R. (Just a couple of thoughts.)

Comment: While I don't recommend it in general, you can get by with nested `fifelse` (data.table) or `ifelse` (base) if `fcase` is problematic. While I think that you really should "find" `fcase` if for no other reason than to verify that `data.table` is performing quickly, at least you can move past this one step for the moment (and come back and fix it). In my opinion, nesting `ifelse` (...) twice is pushing it, three times is a clear case for `fcase` or `dplyr::case_when`.